# xcopy to create folder (drag & drop)

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm using an `xcopy` command so I can drag and drop files on to a batch file:

```
xcopy /s /i "%~1" "D:\folder1"
```

When I drop `folder2` on the batch file, I get this:

> D:\folder1\files

but I want to get this:

> D:\folder1\folder2\files

So I have to copy `folder2` into a separate folder in order for the directory to be created:

> C:\folder3\folder2

That creates the `folder2` directory within `folder1`. What is the switch to eliminate moving `folder2` into a separate folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure?

Comment: What is wrong with `xcopy /s /i "%~1" "D:\folder1\%~nx1"`?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to drag'n drop more than one file/folder at a time you could use this batch. It tests if the current item is a folder and creates the destination if necessary, `shift`s the current argument and loops over.

```
:: DropTarget.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Dest=D:\Test\Bed\"
:loop
if "%~1" equ "" Exit /b 0
echo d|findstr "%~a1" >Nul 2>&1 &&  if not exist "%Dest%%~nx1" Md "%Dest%%~nx1"
xcopy /S /I "%~1" "%Dest%%~nx1"
Shift
Goto :loop
```